# If $A$ is a square matrix of order n such that $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\geq j$, show that $A^n=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have attempted a proof by induction which you can find below, however, I am not sure if it is entirely correct (or even the conventional method?). Could someone please help me out by reviewing it?

---

We assert the following: $$(A^n)_{*m}=0\ , \forall \ m\leq n$$

For $n=2$, the result is valid: $$(A^2)_{*1}=0$$$$(A^2)_{*2}=0$$

Assuming the result is valid for $n=k-1$:$$(A^k)_{*m}=(A^{k-1}\times A)_{*m}$$
$$=\bigg((A^{k-1})_{*1}\times(A)_{1m}\bigg)+\bigg((A^{k-1})_{*2}\times(A)_{2m}\bigg)+\ldots +\bigg((A^{k-1})_{*m-1}\times(A)_{m-1m}\bigg)$$$$=0 \ , \ \forall \ m\leq k$$

Hence, $$(A^n)_{*m}=0\ , \forall \ m\leq n$$$$\Rightarrow A^n=0$$

Comment: A nice effort .…

Comment: What I am trying to establish is that taking the $n_{th}$ power of an upper triangular matrix (with zeros in the diagonal) yields a matrix with the first $n$ columns consisting of only zeros. I have also used the fact that we can express the $m_{th}$ column of $A^{k-1} \times \ A$ as a linear combination of the columns of the $A^{k-1}$. Hope this makes the proof easier to understand.

Comment: What does $B_{* m}$ mean? It's the $m$-th column of a matrix $B$, right? And are you sure you aren't using the letter $n$ for two different things?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what $B_{*m}$ means. About the second question of yours... I suppose I should choose a letter other than $n$ (maybe $p$) within the inductive process and conclude by saying that the result holds true for $p=n$, where $n$ is the order of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, we can consider $A$ as the matrix of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with respect to the standard basis $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $A$ being strictly upper triangular means that
$$
\begin{cases}\tag{*}\label{*}
T(e_{1})=0,\\
T(e_{2})\in\text{Span}\{e_{1}\},\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots\\
T(e_{n})\in\text{Span}\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n-1}\}.
\end{cases}
$$

We can now prove by induction that $T^{j}(e_{j})=0$ for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

**Base step:** For $j=1$, we have $T(e_{1})=0$ by \eqref{*}.

**Inductive step:** Assume $T^{k}(e_{k})=0$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,j\}$. By \eqref{*}, we can write
$$
T(e_{j+1})=c_{1}e_{1}+c_{2}e_{2}+\cdots+c_{j}e_{j}.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
T^{j+1}(e_{j+1})&=T^{j}(T(e_{j+1}))\\
&=T^{j}(c_{1}e_{1}+c_{2}e_{2}+\cdots+c_{j}e_{j})\\
&=c_{1}T^{j-1}(T(e_{1}))+c_{2}T^{j-2}(T^{2}(e_{2}))+\cdots+c_{j-1}T(T^{j-1}(e_{j-1}))+c_{j}T^{j}(e_{j})\\
&=0,
\end{align}
since by the inductive hypothesis
$$
T(e_{1})=T^{2}(e_{2})=\cdots=T^{j-1}(e_{j-1})=T^{j}(e_{j})=0.
$$
In particular, we obtain that $T^{n}(e_{j})=T^{n-j}(T^{j}(e_{j}))=0$ for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So $T^{n}$ maps the basis $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ to zero, and therefore $T^{n}=0$. Consequently, $A^{n}=0$.

Comment: I like this approach. Especially the combination of $T(0)=0$ property of a Linear Transformation, along with splitting $T^n(e_j)$ into $T^{n-j}(T^j(e_j))$ . Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07 I'm glad you like it. Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that $\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^n$. Now use Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Unfortunately, the textbook I am using has not introduced Cayley-Hamilton yet. So I am expected to do it some other way.

Comment: +1 for epic overkill.